# Set Textarea display full in Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have edit.aspx page:

```
<body style="background-color: rgb(225, 255, 255)">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table style="width: 100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 1%" align="right">
                            <span id="LabelCapFileName" style="white-space:nowrap">File name:</span>                
                        </td>
                         <td>
                            <span id="LabelFileName" style="font-weight:bold;">About.asp</span>
                        </td>
                        <td align="right">
                                <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Lưu" />
                         </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style=" position: absolute; top: 45px; bottom: 5px;
                        left: 5px; right: 5px">

                        <textarea id="code" name="code" runat="server"  wrap="off" style=" width:99%; height:99%" >               
                          </textarea>
               </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>   

</div>      
    </form>
```

Even the Textarea has `style=" width:99%; height:99%"`, it still display small in a left srceen.

[image]

I want the Text Area auto display full of Chrome Browser like:

[image]

I dont know what make the textarea display as the wrong way. Is there any mistake in my code above, I need your opinion to finish my project. Help!!

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? I created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/REgjn/) with your markup and it fills the display fine.

Comment: Poor me, I really don't know why , I'm using version >30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set the doctype in your HeaderContent control?

If not, do so:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

If you still have problems, you could try setting `style:width:100%; height:100%;` on the `textarea` control's `td` element also, possibly also on the `html` and `body` elements like so:

```
html,body,#code
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

If you open this in a browser and "View Source" and paste it here it would be easier to troubleshoot your problem.

Comment: thanks you, really nice way, the textarea displays full right now. Thank again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a stupid question. But why you are using a single div instide the td element? Could it be possible, that you are limited by the div instead of the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should use rows and cols property of textarea. You can change the rows and cols according to your requirements.

```
 <textarea id="code" name="code" runat="server" rows="50" cols="80"  wrap="off">               
 </textarea>
```

Comment: thank you, I've known it already, it not auto full the chrome browser when I expand the browser

Answer (score 0):

The table above your text area is at 100% width, instead put width on all your td tags, this is better practice than putting width on tables.