# Textarea style is auto covered by element.style

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page, I have a textarea:

```
<div style=" position: absolute; top: 45px; bottom: 5px;
                        left: 5px; right: 5px">

                        <textarea id="code" name="code" runat="server"  wrap="off" style="clear: both; width:99%; height:99%" >               
                          </textarea>
               </div>
```

All I want is the Textarea auto display full the browser. But when I built the page, the text area just display small in the left browser screen.

Try to press F12, the Textarea tag is changed:

```
 <textarea id="code" name="code" runat="server"  wrap="off" style="display:block" >  </textarea>
```

Really tired, I met this situation for many times. Sometimes, I add `style= "clear:both"` but in this situation, it cannot help.

The Textarea 's style is just contain: `display:block`

I copy my code to  http://jsfiddle.net/REgjn/ ---> it display as the way I expected: the textarea is fill full the chrome browser.  But it is not when I built it on the real browser.

Help!!!
Why is the TextArea tag changed???

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. I hope it will work

```
           <div style=" position: absolute; top: 45px; bottom: 5px;
                    left: 5px; right: 5px;width:99%; height:99%">

                    <textarea id="code" name="code" runat="server"  wrap="off" style="clear: both; width:99%; height:99%" >               
                      </textarea>
           </div>
```

Comment: I have tested this code in chrome and IE. Your code was working as expected in chrome but not in IE. when i made the changes it was working fine for both the browsers.

Comment: use this, if it works try some workaround <textarea id="code" name="code" runat="server"  wrap="off" style="clear: both; width:500px; height:500px" >               
                      </textarea>

Comment: hope you can take a look at my whole code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19568070/set-textarea-display-full-in-chrome . I dont know why the textarea cannot display as I expected.